# Simplify SQL Query into a shorter query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a log table which contains the summary of the claims. The log table log's the data whenever there is an upload.

I have wrote the following sql query. Though it serves the purpose I'm trying to learn whether there is any way to simplify the below updates.

```
CREATE TABLE #1 
  ( 
     id                         INT IDENTITY(1, 1), 
     [total no claims]          INT, 
     [total claims inserted]    INT, 
     [total claims errored out] INT, 
     [erroed claims]            VARCHAR(max) 
  ) 

INSERT INTO #1 
            ([total no claims]) 
SELECT Count(DISTINCT [claimnumber]) 
FROM   [Operations Productivity Tool].[dbo].[test_importedauditdata] ta 
WHERE  claimnumber IN (SELECT DISTINCT claimnumber 
                       FROM   [dbo].[opcod audit information] ts 
                       WHERE  [final status] IN ( 'Finding', 'No Finding' )) 
       AND id = Scope_identity() 

UPDATE #1 
SET    [total claims inserted] = (SELECT Count(DISTINCT [claimnumber]) 
                                  FROM 
              [Operations Productivity Tool].[dbo].[test_importedauditdata] ta 
                                  WHERE  claimnumber NOT IN 
                                         (SELECT DISTINCT claimnumber 
                                          FROM   [dbo].[opcod audit information] 
                                                 ts 
                                          WHERE  [final status] IN ( 
                                                 'Finding', 'No Finding' ) 
                                         )) 
WHERE  id = Scope_identity() 

UPDATE #1 
SET    [total claims errored out] = (SELECT 
       [total no claims] - [total claims inserted] 
                                     FROM   #1) 
WHERE  id = Scope_identity() 

UPDATE #1 
SET    [erroed claims] = (SELECT 
                                Stuff ((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + claimnumber 
                                         FROM 
       [Operations Productivity Tool].[dbo].[test_importedauditdata] 
                WHERE  claimnumber NOT IN 
                       (SELECT DISTINCT claimnumber 
                        FROM   [dbo].[opcod audit information] ts 
                        WHERE  [final status] NOT IN ( 
                               'Finding', 'No Finding' )) 
                FOR xml 
       path(''), type).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')) 
WHERE  id = Scope_identity()
```

Is there any way to convert the above sql to a shorter version.

Comment: Well, you could for example not use a table if all you need is variables.

Comment: Why do not use `;with cte` statement. You don't need temp table. Moreover you just need re-think your logic. Your 2 updates just different by where clause.

Comment: This question isn't appropriate for StackOverflow. Please post it to [StackExchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method of creating a temp and then just use UPDATE statement to update each column would kill the query performance, and you'll notice that in larger tables. Even if you're using temp tables, it doesn't mean this will make it faster.

There are many ways to get the output you need with minimal effort. For instance, you could use aggregate functions with the help of JOINs to get the same results in one query.

As for me, I can see your output will be a single row with total claims, total inserted, total error, and list of errored claim numbers. So, I'm assuming the output will be always a single row each time the procedure runs.

In this case, you can use variables, would be something like this :

```
DECLARE 
    @Total              INT
,   @TotalInserted      INT
,   @TotalErroredOut    INT
,   @ErroredClaims      NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT 
    @Total           =  SUM(CASE WHEN ta.[claimnumber] IN (d.claimnumber) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
,   @TotalInserted   =  SUM(CASE WHEN ta.[claimnumber] NOT IN (d.claimnumber) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
,   @TotalErroredOut =  SUM(CASE WHEN ta.[claimnumber] IN (d.claimnumber) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN ta.[claimnumber] NOT IN (d.claimnumber) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
,   @ErroredClaims   =  COALESCE(@col + ',', '') + CASE WHEN ta.[claimnumber] NOT IN (d.claimnumber) THEN ta.[claimnumber] ELSE '' END
FROM   
    [Operations Productivity Tool].[dbo].[test_importedauditdata] ta 
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT DISTINCT claimnumber 
    FROM   [dbo].[opcod audit information] ts 
    WHERE  
        [final status] NOT IN ('Finding', 'No Finding')
) d 
WHERE  
    claimnumber IN (d.claimnumber)
```

and then, use the declared variables in your next action.

The code example above could contain errors, but it's just to show you another way of thinking, and might lead you to a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Ditch the session table. If you want to use separate evolving result sets, use CTE instead (the data sets can't be huge for this option).

You might want to throw this on codereview.stackexchange.com.